# Multiple traces in plotly js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, plotly

I'm getting a bit stuck trying to efficiently plot multiple traces in plotly js. I'm generating 3 charts from 66 traces, each with about 12 values/rows (~12*66 = 792 values total, not per chart). The traces are represented in memory and mapped to objects like so:

```
`var dataMapped2 = data2.map(function(dataMap){
   return {
      x: unpack(data2, "rowIndex"),
      y: unpack (data2, "bytes"),
      type: "scatter",
      mode: "markers",          
      name: "Trace X",
   };
});`
```

I can successfully plot the traces with:

```
Plotly.plot(BYTESCHART, dataMapped1, layout, {showLink: false});
Plotly.addTraces(BYTESCHART, dataMapped2);
Plotly.addTraces(BYTESCHART, dataMapped3);
```

But it takes minutes just to open the local HTML file that displays the charts.
I've tried assigning the traces to arrays:

```
var traceArray1 = dataMapped1, dataMapped2;
```

which may have worked with a couple (~3) traces, but only a single trace shows up when the entire set is passed to addTraces();

I don't see any console errors. Any ideas?
Much appreciated.

Comment: cant you just use `Plotly.plot(BYTESCHART, [dataMapped1,dataMapped2,dataMapped3], layout, {showLink: false});` this will plot all the traces at once, let me know if this increases the performance in any way

Comment: Just tried that, the chart shows as blank... The traces are even the same number of rows, with the same x values.

Comment: please provide a plunkr/codepen example with dummy data to analyze, just a suggestion remove the layout in plotly.plot function and check again

Comment: I'll provide a plunkr/codepen example in a couple hours (haven't used them before). First however, going to try to convert the traces to a straight json format and see if that works & is fast enough `(x:  [1,15,25,45,58,77,90,109,122,142,152,174]` directly listed instead of mapping from a csv style format. I'm parsing a CSV with Perl so I'm trying to use `var rawCSVResults2 =` ```column1,column2...``` then `var data2 = Plotly.d3.csv.parse(rawCSVResults2);` somewhat strangely... Will update this if the json conversion works..!

Comment: Converted to the json format. This dataset will grow, so I'm a bit worried that these json objects will become unwieldy eventually, but with 16 traces and only 1 chart, the load time is instantaneous. Really appreciate the support here, I could have gone down the wrong road with this one. Any more insight or why addTraces()/using csv.parse on vars would slow down perf and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge since we do the bulky work before hand and send the JSON alone; instead of taking the csv file and generating the objects with script, we get a faster result compared to before, if you feel the data will get unwieldly you need to add dropdowns and filters to make the graph and data more understandable, but that is a whole other ball game altogether. Let me know if I can include an answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151335/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-user176692).